# Under which assumptions we have $f\in L^p$ for all $p\in\mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

So here is my question,

I wanted to generalize, under what assumptions for some $f$ we have $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)\;\forall p\in\mathbb N.$

And I found the following,

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for some $p\in\mathbb N$ and assume that for $A:=\{x\;:|f(x)|<1\}$ we have,

$$\mu(A)<\infty$$

for an arbitrary measure. Furthermore assume that $\exists C\in\mathbb R$ s.t $|f(x)|\geq C\;\forall x\mathbb\in R$ i.e $f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$

Then $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)\;\forall p\in\mathbb N.$

Proof:

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for some $p\in\mathbb N$ and assume that for $A:=\{x\;:|f(x)|<1\}$ we have,

$$\mu(A)<\infty$$

Then for any $1\leq q\leq p$ the following holds,

$$\int_{A^C}|f|^qd\mu\leq\int_{A^C}|f|^pd\mu\leq\int_{\mathbb R}|f|^pd\mu<\infty$$
and,

$$ \int_{A}|f|^qd\mu\leq\int_{A}1d\mu=\mu(A)<\infty$$
Hence,

$$\int_{\mathbb R }|f|^qd\mu=\int_{A^C}|f|^qd\mu+\int_{A}|f|^qd\mu\leq\mu(A)+\int_{\mathbb R}|f|^pd\mu<\infty$$
This yields $f\in L^q$ for all $q\leq p$.

Now let $k>p$. Since $k\in\mathbb N$ there exist an positive integer $r$ s.t $k\mod p=r$.
Moreover there exists an $n$ s.t $k=pn+r$.

Hence,

$$\int_{\mathbb R}|f|^kd\mu=\int_{\mathbb R}|f|^{np}|f|^rd\mu\leq C^{np}\int_{\mathbb R}|f|^r<\infty$$
since $r\leq p.$

Hence $f\in L^k$ and since $k$ was arbitrary the claim follows.

Is this proof correct? And If yes, is there a possibility to relax the assumption that $f$ has to be bounded?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I just see that the second part is redundant because every bounded and integrable $f$ is contained in $L^p$ for all $p$...

Comment: $f(x) = \log(1/x) \chi_{(0,1)}(x)$ is an unbounded function in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $1 \le p < \infty$, so $f \in L^\infty$ is not a necessary condition.

Comment: @J.J Yes, but without assuming that $f$ is bounded I could only show that if $f\in L^p$ and $\mu(A)<\infty$ then $f\in L^q$ with $1\leq q\leq k$ and I really would like to find weak assumptions such that $f\in L^p$ for all $p$...

Comment: Sure - my comment was meant as a side note. You have to have some condition on the growth of $f$ in order to prove a result like the one you are after.